# How do I change a '\' to a '/'

Tags: c#, javascript, url, browser

My web program is getting an error when trying to access a file in a code behind C# program that has a backward slash between the directory name and the file name.  The address for the file comes into my web page with a query value of 'deaths\bakerd.htm'.  The browser, however, converts it to 'deaths%08akerd.htm'.

The url in the webpage reads

```
 'http://localhost:57602/obitm.aspx?url=deaths%08akerd.htm'
```

and says the web page cannot be found but the webpage obitm.aspx does exist so why would it say it doesn't?

If I manually change the value of the query value in Windows Explorer to 'deaths/bakerd.htm' it doesn't do any conversion when coming in as a query value in the browser and I am able to access the file in my C# program.

I tried to change the query value in javascript using

```
   thisurl = url.replace("\\", "/")
```

but that didn't change anything.

I haven't tried any conversion in my C# program.  So how do I programmatically change the '\' to a '/'?  I have no idea why this is happening and is very confusing.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Converting \ to / in the URL string won't work for you, because in this case the "\b" is being turned into the backspace character which gets encoded into %08 - which is the HEX value for the ASCII equivalent of the backspace character.

To fix this one occurrence, you could convert the "%08" into the string "/B" but there are lots of [HTML codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for the various characters that it would not be productive or fun for you to try.

Where are you getting the original string containing the file name name from? 
If it is something that you have control over then convert the "\" to "/" at the point when you read the path / name of the file and before you pass it in a URL to the Web App.

you could also HTMLEncode the path before sending it so that the string becomes

```
http://localhost:57602/obitm.aspx?url=deaths%92Bakerd.htm'
```

Comment: Thanks to those who responded but nothing has helped.  I do the following conversion in javascript:

       function getthisObit(url) {
            window.location = "obitm.aspx?url=" + url.replace("\\", "/");;
        }

I put in an alert in the obitm.aspx script but it never gets there.  Instead, it gives the error message and it never gets to the C# program where I can edit it further.  So I cannot convert the '\' in javascript and the browser gives me an error saying it is an invalid url even though the url is ok, it is just the query data that is wrong.

Comment: Could you add in the code that shows how you get url, before  you  before you call getthisObit() ...

Comment: Thanks for triggering a thought.  I did the conversion in my C# program when building the page which contained the link and it solved the problem.  In my C# program I did this when building the page:  finalrecord = finalrecord.Replace("\\", "/");  So now when I click on it to get the link it is already in its correct format. So the conversion of "\\" to "/' works in C# but not in javascript. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using verbatim string by prefixing with @ symbol

```
string url = @"http://localhost:57602/obitm.aspx?url=deaths\bakerd.htm".Replace("\\","/").ToString();
```

Comment: +1. Or if string comes  from JavaScript - "death\\bakerd.htm" (`\b` is single character with code 8, which is neither `\` nor `/`)

Answer (score 0):

try `thisurl = url.Replace("\\", "/");` 
Just like in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To parse query string parameter, you can user:

```
NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
```

[Here us MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)

or you can:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["url"]);
```